# Hierarchical Queries inside Join

Tags: oracle, hierarchical

I'm facing one annoying problema and I would like some help.

This is the situation.

```
CREATE TABLE tree_hierarchy (
  id        NUMBER (20)
 ,parent_id NUMBER (20)
);
CREATE TABLE tree_information (
  id        NUMBER (20)
 ,some_text VARCHAR(20)
 ,tree_id NUMBER (20)
);
INSERT INTO tree_hierarchy (id, parent_id) VALUES (2, null);
INSERT INTO tree_hierarchy (id, parent_id) VALUES (4, 2);
INSERT INTO tree_hierarchy (id, parent_id) VALUES (9, 4);
INSERT INTO tree_hierarchy (id, parent_id) VALUES (20, null);
INSERT INTO tree_hierarchy (id, parent_id) VALUES (40, 20);
INSERT INTO tree_hierarchy (id, parent_id) VALUES (90, 40);
INSERT INTO tree_information (id, some_text, tree_id) VALUES (10,'Some teste', 2);
INSERT INTO tree_information (id, some_text, tree_id) VALUES (11,'Other tree', 20);
```

And i would like to do something like this.

```
SELECT hier.*
  FROM tree_information Ti
  JOIN (
        SELECT 
            id,
            parent_id
         FROM tree_hierarchy th
         where connect_by_isleaf = 1
        START WITH th.id = ti.tree_id
        CONNECT BY PRIOR th.id = th.parent_id


  ) hier on 1=1;
```

but ti.tree_id is not visible inside the select.

If I change the start with condition for

```
 START WITH th.parent_id is null
```

Will stay wrong.
Someone has idea how to solve this situation ?

Comment: Can you please show what your expected output should be?

Comment: "Here is what I want to do" and then after that you show code, which DOESN'T do what you want to do (this is why you are posting this in the first place). So how are we supposed to guess what you DO want to do? From code that DOESN'T do it, and nothing else? Please see what OldProgrammer wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

I would appreciate if you provide expected result explicitly.
My best guess is:

```
SELECT hier.*, ti.*
  FROM tree_information Ti
  JOIN (
        SELECT 
            id,
            parent_id,
            connect_by_root th.id as tree_id
         FROM tree_hierarchy th
         where connect_by_isleaf = 1
        START WITH th.id in ( select tii.tree_id from tree_information Tii)
        CONNECT BY PRIOR th.id = th.parent_id
  ) hier on ti.tree_id = hier.tree_id;

ID  PARENT_ID   TREE_ID ID  SOME_TEXT   TREE_ID
 9          4         2 10  Some teste        2
90         40        20 11  Other tree       20
```